# Neo4j in memory db

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, network-analysis

I saw Neo4j can run as Impermanent DB for unit testing porpouses, I'm not sure if this fits my needs. I have my data stored in neo4j the usual way (persistent) but, starts from my data, I want to let each user start an "experimental session": the users add/delete nodes and relationships, but NOT in permanent way, just experimenting with the data (after that session the edits should be lost). The edits shouldn't be saved and obiouvsly they shouldn't be visibile to the others. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Using impermanent database should work. You would

- need to import the data to each new database
- spring-data-neo4j is not able to connect to multiple databases (in current release), you would need to start multiple instances of your application, e.g. in a tomcat container
- when your application stops (or crashes) you would obviously lose data

Or you could potentially use only 1 database with the base data being public (= visible to everyone) and then for all new nodes/relationships you can add owner property.

When querying the data you would check the property is either public or the current user.

At the end of the session you would just delete all nodes and relationships with given owner.

If you also want to edit existing data then it gets more complicated, you could create a copy of the node/relationship and somehow handle that, or if it's not too large copy whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a docker image from the neo4j base image (or build your own) and copy your graph.db into it.

Then you can have every user start a docker container from said image.

If that doesn't answer your question, more info is needed.

Comment: I mean end-user, an user which barely can use a browser  :)
I don't think that create a docker container each user, even developing a zero-configuration 'startup', could be a solution.